# cannot add dynamic jtextfields and save their values

Tags: java, swing

In previos my questions I asked similar questions to this. But in my previous projects I used GUI builder, so now I would like to add `JTextField` to the `Panel` dynamically without Builder. I don't why but for some reason I cannot execute this code:

```
public class Reference {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel MainPanel = new JPanel();
    MainPanel main = new MainPanel();
    JPanel SubPanel = new JPanel();
    JButton addButton = new JButton();
    JButton saveButton = new JButton();
    private List<JTextField> listTf = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       new Reference();
    }

    public Reference() {
        frame.add(main);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(addButton, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.add(saveButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(500, 300); 
        frame.setVisible(true);
        main.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
        main.setBackground(Color.green);                 
        main.add(SubPanel);
        SubPanel.setBackground(Color.yellow);

        addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    main.add(new SubPanel());
                    main.revalidate();
                }
            }); 

        saveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < main.getComponentCount();) {
                SubPanel panel = (SubPanel)main.getComponent(i);
                JTextField firstName = panel.getFirstName();
                String text = firstName.getText();
                System.out.println( text );
  }}
      });

    }

    private class SubPanel extends JPanel {   

       JTextField firstName = new JTextField(15);

    public SubPanel() {

            this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
            this.add(firstName);
      listTf.add(firstName);
        }
    public JTextField getFirstName()
{
    return firstName;
}
    } 


  public class MainPanel extends JPanel
{
    List<SubPanel> subPanels = new ArrayList<SubPanel>();

    public MainPanel()
    {
    }

    public void addSubPanel()
    {
        SubPanel panel = new SubPanel();
        add(panel);
        subPanels.add(panel);
    }

   public SubPanel getSubPanel(int index)
    {
        return subPanels.get(index);
    }
  }
}
```

And by `saveButton` trying to get value of `JTextField`, but without success. In output I can see just `JFrame` with 2 `Buttons`, but `ActionListener` of `addButton` and `saveButton` is not active. I cannot understand where is wrong.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can start by not doing this -> `SubPanel panel = (SubPanel) main.getComponent(i);` within `for (int i = 0; i < main.getComponentCount();) {`. You are blindly casting components without knowing what they are and your `for-loop` will only ever compare the first component, for ever...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swing, the order you do some things is very important, for example...

```
frame.add(main);
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.add(addButton, BorderLayout.EAST);
frame.add(saveButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
frame.pack();
frame.setSize(500, 300); 
frame.setVisible(true);
```

1. You add `main` to your `frame`
2. You set the frames layout (!?)
3. You add your buttons
4. You pack the frame
5. You set it's size (!?)
6. You make it visible

The problem here is step #2.  If, instead, we simply remove step #2 (step #4 and #5 aren't great either), you will find that your window now contains `main`...

```
frame.add(main);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.add(addButton, BorderLayout.EAST);
frame.add(saveButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

This...

```
for (int i = 0; i < main.getComponentCount();) {
    SubPanel panel = (SubPanel) main.getComponent(i);
```

a bad idea of three reasons;

1. Your loop will never advance (`i` will always be `0`)
2. You are blindly casting the contents of `main` without actually knowing what's on it
3. `MainPanel` already has a `List` of `SubPanel`s...

You need to make sure that you are adding `SubPanel`s via the `addSubPanel` method (and this should probably return an instance of the `SubPanel`) and provide a means by which you can access this `List`, maybe via a `getter` of some sort.  Although, I'd be more interested in their values (ie the text field text) rather then the `SubPanel` itself ;)

Comment: You will need to reference the `SubPanel` of `Main`, which is why I suggest you needed another getter

Comment: Write a getter in MainPanel which returns the list of SubPanels and use it to extract the details you want